# Retrieve the dotted path of an object?

Tags: python, python-3.x, object

let say some function from a collaborator will get me an object, a property from a class.
i do not have access to this function, all I have is the given object.

```
def get_color():
    """this function will get you a color property from a nested class"""
    ...
    return color
```

How could i retrieve the dotted path of the object like this below

```
>>> color = get_color()
>>> API = find_string_api(color)
>>> print(API)
"parent_dylan.children[56].color"
```

Comment: I would say you can't because who says that the one color is *only* defined there? If I have another place where I return that color why shouldn't *that* place be the correct path?

Comment: What is `parent_dylan`? What is `parent_dylan.children[56]`? Where are they defined?

Comment: Just to be clear, when you say "property", you mean a [`property`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/functions.html#property), right? and not a regular attribute?

Comment: You might need to read [Facts and myths about Python names and values](https://nedbatchelder.com/text/names.html) by Ned Batchelder to make sense of what you're really asking.